# My custom pipeline is not executing if trigger from any Sitecore CMS pages other than Experience Platform screen

Tags: pipelines

Here is my issue, I have patched a custom pipeline before the "GotoLogin" pipeline, in order to redirect a user to a custom login page post user's clicked on the logout button. My patch config as follows,

```
<speak.logout><processor type="Foundation.Identity.Pipelines.OktaAuthentication.OktaLogout, Foundation.Identity" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.GotoLogin, Sitecore.Kernel']"/></speak.logout>
```

This works when user clicks the logout button from Experience Platform page, but if the user tries to logout from any other page it won't execute my custom pipeline, Is there any reason for this behaviour??

It would be helpful if I get some inputs or any suggestions.

Thanks

Bharath S

Comment: Did you write this processor for logout from Speak Applications?

Comment: I need to patch a pipeline in order to update "arg.RedirectUrl" so used speak

Comment: Have you also tried to have a processor added in <logout argsType="Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.LogoutArgs">? Similar to the existing one <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.GotoLogin, Sitecore.Kernel" />

Comment: @CristiVulturar yes I tried to patch on <logout> tag, then even my pipeline was not hit

Comment: I got solution, configuration has to be like below 

<processors>
   <logout argsType="Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.LogoutArgs">
    <processor patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.GotoLogin, Sitecore.Kernel']" mode="on"
    type="Foundation.Identity.Pipelines.OktaAuthentication.OktaLogout, Foundation.Identity" /></logout>
</processors>